# Lion 32bit kext failed to load for pure virtual function but 64bit works

Tags: usb, osx-lion, 32-bit, kernel-extension

I build a virtual USB Bus (communicating via network with an linux box) as kext for OSX.
The main class is derived from an IOUSBControllerV3.

It works under 10.6 32Bit, 10.7.5 64bit, 10.8 64bit, but failed to load
under 10.7.5 32bit due to (a?) pure virtual function. kextutil told me this.

I've compiled (Xcode 4.6) the kext under the same system, tried a lot of variations
which target system or SDK versions, but the problem is still resident?

I know that there are some #ifdef **LP64** differences in the headers of the
base classes, especially in context of the pure virtual functions.

But after two days of comparing and comparing the overloadings of the
pure virtual functions I have no idea why only 32bit makes trouble?

The same code works under the other systems, but Lion 32bit does not.

Many thanks in advance for every hint,

regards
    Markus

=========== terminal output:

```
MacProTest:Developer ms$ sudo kextutil -t -v 2   MaCute.kext
Password:
Notice: MaCute.kext has debug properties set.
MaCute.kext appears to be loadable (not including linkage for on-disk libraries).
Loading MaCute.kext.
Reading load info for 13 kexts.
Created mkext for architecture i386 containing 1 kexts.
Loading MaCute.kext.
(kernel) Received request from user space to load kext de.seh.utn.MaCute.
(kernel) Loading kext de.seh.utn.MaCute.
(kernel) Allocated link buffer for kext de.seh.utn.MaCute at 0x1507000 (200704 bytes).
(kernel) kxld[de.seh.utn.MaCute]: This kext calls a pure virtual function. Make sure your kext's OSObject-derived classes implement all pure virtual functions.
(kernel) Can't load kext de.seh.utn.MaCute - link failed.
(kernel) Failed to load executable for kext de.seh.utn.MaCute.
(kernel) Kext de.seh.utn.MaCute failed to load (0xdc008016).
(kernel) Failed to load kext de.seh.utn.MaCute (error 0xdc008016).
Failed to load MaCute.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
Failed to load MaCute.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
Check library declarations for your kext with kextlibs(8).
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the function is (or the exact output from kextutil)? Also, have you checked the system log or run kextutil in verbose (-v) mode?

Comment: Hi, I've added the kextutil output. I would be glad to know which function is the problem, but know no way to find it out. Are there any tool to detect the problem function? It seems to depend on the IOUSBController class, but there are a lot of pure virtual functions and all seems to be clean overloaded (works on 64bit and other systems)?

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't find any obvious culprits in the `IOUSBControllerV3.h` header file, I decided to Google for the error message in an attempt to find the relevant source code. I've traced it back to the function `check_for_direct_pure_virtual_call()` in [kxld_reloc.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/libkern/kxld/kxld_reloc.c):

```
    entry = kxld_vtable_get_entry_for_offset(relocator->current_vtable, 
        offset, relocator->is_32_bit);
    require_action(!entry || !entry->patched.name ||
        !kxld_sym_name_is_pure_virtual(entry->patched.name),
        finish, rval=KERN_FAILURE;
        kxld_log(kKxldLogLinking, kKxldLogErr, 
            kKxldLogDirectPureVirtualCall));
```

`kKxldLogDirectPureVirtualCall` is `#define`d as that error.

If I were you, I'd download the xnu source package for that osx version (1699.32.7) and build your own kernel binary, using the instructions [on this site](http://shantonu.blogspot.com/). Then, modify the above function to output `entry->patched.name` if the assertion condition fails, so insert this before the `require_action()` line:

```
if (entry && entry->patched.name && kxld_sym_name_is_pure_virtual(entry->patched.name))
printf("pure virtual function called by kext: %s\n", entry->patched.name);
```

Then rebuild and boot the new kernel. I think this should print the (mangled) name of the function to the kernel log. It's quite a bit of effort, but I think it'll get you there!

**Update:**

From the comments it's clear we're not quite there yet. On i386, `check_for_direct_pure_virtual_call()` is called from `generic_process_reloc()`, which will report failure if the pure virtual check fails:

```
rval = check_for_direct_pure_virtual_call(relocator, instr_data);
require_noerr(rval, finish);
```

There's nothing terribly helpful to us in this function, but it in turn is called from 2 functions: `kxld_relocator_process_sect_reloc()` and `kxld_relocator_process_table_reloc()`. I don't know which one applies in this case, but the code in both looks very similar, so we can modify them both in the same way with debug output:

```
rval = relocator->process_reloc(relocator, instruction, reloc->length, 
    reloc->pcrel, base_pc, link_pc, link_disp, reloc->reloc_type, target, 
    pair_target, relocator->swap);
require_noerr(rval, finish);
```

We want to insert code between those two statements: the first is the relocation call that fails, the second bails out of the function. We want to catch failures and generate some debug output for them. So, something like this:

```
rval = relocator->process_reloc(relocator, instruction, reloc->length, 
    reloc->pcrel, base_pc, link_pc, link_disp, reloc->reloc_type, target, 
    pair_target, relocator->swap);

if (rval)
{
  // try to find the symbol corresponding to this relocation entry
  KXLDSym* sym = kxld_reloc_get_symbol(relocator, reloc, NULL);
  const char* symname = (sym && sym->name) ? sym->name : "[NULL]";
  const char* symalias = (sym && sym->alias) ? sym->alias : "[NULL]";
  printf("Relocation failed for relocation %p, symbol %p: name = '%s', alias = '%s'\n",
    reloc, sym, symname, symalias);
}

require_noerr(rval, finish);
```

Modify both functions, build a kernel, boot it, and try to load your kext. I'm hoping that this will get you something to work with. Let us know how you get on!

Note that I haven't tested the above code as I currently have no way of reproducing the problem.

Comment: I was a little bit afraid of that kind of answer, but thank you very much to detect the relevant line. I will try it and keep you inf

Comment: Compiling your own kernel is actually not that hard - the instructions on the linked site are quite clear (make sure to use the right ones for your version) and once you've downloaded everything it should only take a few minutes, depending on how fast your computer is of course. The site seems to be run by Santonu Sen, one of the kernel developers at Apple, so it's first-hand information.

Comment: Yes, it sounds so easy. Following the instructions and tried some others too without success. One of the environments I've tried is a MacBookPro 8.1 with the problematic 10.7.5 and Xcode 4.4.1 (update running) GCC 4.2.1 GNU Make 3.81. Some sites suggested first of all to build an cxxfilt-9 which fails on error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]. Maybe my compiler settings are too restrictive.

Comment: Yes I know this is not the focus of this thread and shame on me, I have 20 years experience of coding and linux kernels and to build the xnu kernels should be easy as a sunshine pinic. Thank you very much so far, I try to make the patched kernel.

Comment: I generally recommend building on the same version of OSX as the kernel you're building (so 10.7.5) and using the same minor version of Xcode as Apple used. You can find this out from the "DTXcodeBuild" property in the info.plist of any of their kexts. I checked, and for 10.7.5, this seems to be Xcode 4.1. (DTXcode is 0410). After installing that version, you'll need to make it the default using the xcode-select terminal command. Good luck!

Comment: I forgot to add: also make sure to install the CLI utilities for that version of Xcode. Might be easiest to set up a VM just for building the kernel for such old kernels, that way it won't interfere with your normal xcode.

Comment: Ok, after some dark hours I decide to take a clean partition, install 10.7.0, update to 10.7.5, install xcode 4.1 and latest (maybe not neccessary) CLI utilities Feb.13 and every thing works so simple. Then copy the new i386 mach kernel to the (backuped) original and boot. And running into the "Still waiting for root device" loop. I read about boot options like "-rd=disk0s3" (it's may 2nd partition) or ncpi=0x3000, but find, so for, no point to set boot parameters? Have I to add them in the make process? I think this problem is solvable, keep you informed, many thanks so far!

Comment: Ok, took the wrong xnu-1699.22.73, the present xnu-1699.32.7 is starting, great! But cann't find my message:-( Kernel is the self made, "uname -a" verifies. hmmm...

Comment: Now I got the information @pmjordan (many thanks) suggested. Hmm, but I'm not sure if this will really help me. The entry->patched.name is "___cxa_pure_virtual", what looks more than a placeholder or relocation address than a function name. I will try to find it.

Comment: OK, glad you finally got it up and running, I'm sorry to hear the debug output isn't helping much. I'll take a look at the surrounding code and see if you can output anything more helpful.

Comment: So, I've just done some digging around in that code. On x86, `check_for_direct_pure_virtual_call()` is called by `generic_process_reloc()`, which in turn is called via the statement `rval = relocator->process_reloc(relocator, instruction, reloc->length, 
        reloc->pcrel, base_pc, link_pc, link_disp, reloc->reloc_type, target, 
        pair_target, relocator->swap);` in the function `kxld_relocator_process_sect_reloc()` or a very similar line in `kxld_relocator_process_table_reloc()` (all still in kxld_reloc.c). At both sites we have access to the relocation entry. (`KXLDReloc* reloc`)

Comment: The relocation entry isn't necessarily interesting in itself (we could use it to find the place in your code that calls the bad function), but we should be able to get to the symbol corresponding to it, which will have the name. So, I suggest after those `process_reloc()` calls, you insert a failure check and try to look up the symbol via `kxld_reloc_get_symbol()`. That should return a `KXLDSym` structure, which has "name" and "alias" fields, which hopefully will contain something useful. I'll update the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer. If that doesn't get you there, it might be more efficient to contact me off stack overflow, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I got MS:process_sect Relocation failed for relocation 0x855b8b40, symbol 0x85875d64: name = '__ZTV17IOUSBControllerV3', alias = '[NULL]'what open the door into the kernel->libusb framework. It looks a little bit odd to me because I tried some variation without ControllerV3 calls. But maybe the ControllerV3 is only the top of the derivation. Google give some hits but no meat:-(

Comment: I made a lot of "strings ..dSYM/.../DWARF/*|grep -i V17Controll" but can not find the symbol nor in the .kext.dSYM wether in framework oder KDEKit_10_7 dSYM files? Out of which universe this symbol comes from?

Comment: Hmm, `__ZTV17IOUSBControllerV3` is the vtable for IOUSBControllerV3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25615/discussion-between-pmjordan-and-markus-steinmann)